# Model A::B belongs_to foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have a model A::B which has_many model C, what do i name the foreign key?

```
Class A::B
 has_many :c

Class C
 belongs_to :a_b
```

In the database Table C has a column a_b_id.
This does not work. Any idea what i am missing? the :: are what i am confused about. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `B` is in a different namespace, you'll need to specify it in your class `C`.

```
class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a_b, :class_name => "A::B"
end
```

since you're using `a_b_id` and not `b_id`, you'll need to specify the foreign key in `A::B`

```
class A::B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :c, :foreign_key => "a_b_id"
end
```

Alternatively, you could use the following set up to avoid having to specify a foreign key in `A::B`

```
class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b, :class_name => "A::B"
end

class A::B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :c
end
```

This would require `b_id` in the table for `C`